# Using OpenNMS, how can I disable notifications for a particular service and server

Tags: monitoring, opennms

We are using OpenNMS to monitor a pool of servers, and we have a problem with SMTP in one particular box. OpenNMS is "spamming" us all the time with DOWN/RESOLVED messages for that particular service in that server, and I wanted to mute those notifications momentarely but couldn't find how to do that. I know that I can disable ALL notifications or disable SMTP in ALL servers, but that's not what I want.

I'm used to muting a particular service in Nagios, but is it possible in OpenNMS?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **Home** / **Search** / **Node List** and select the specific Node you have a problem with.
2. In the Node Management page goto **Admin** > **Manage and Unmanage Interfaces and Services**.
3. Deselect the service you wish unmanaged and click Apply Changes.

In the availability view of the node the SMTP service should now read something like "Forced Unmanaged".

Answer (score 0):

I think you're stuck with creating a `Scheduled outage` for the node in question OR unmanaging the service in question on the specific node.

```
Admin -> Manage and Unmanage Interfaces and Services 
Uncheck SMTP for the right interface and Apply Changes

Return to the node's page and run a rescan to activate the changes.
```